# Spring boot feign fallback addtional parameters

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, feign

I'm implementing a client feign with a hystrix fallback; My problem is that the fallback class calls an API that uses some different data from the clientFeign.
So, my question is: is there a way to pass some additional parameters to my feign, so it can be used just by the fallback class?

```
@FeignClient(name = "${feign.inventory.name}", url = "${feign.inventory.url:}", fallbackFactory = StockFallback.class)
public interface StockClient {

@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/{sku}/{groupId}", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
  produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
List<ItemStock> getStockSkuAndInventoryGroup(@PathVariable("sku") final String sku,
  @PathVariable("groupId") final String groupId);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to define another parameter that is not mapped into any path variable or query param ? And just use it inside your fallback method.

Comment: It's not currently possible to pass additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As spencergibb pointted there is no possibilities of passing an adittional parameter to use in a histrix feign fall back.
So we developed anew end-point which uses the same data as the original, so that the fallback take on clearly and transparent.